# Algorithms for encrypting a PIN code (4 purely random digits) into same-sized cipher text

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

We have PIN codes that need encryption, that are purely random and aren't selectable by user.

They have to be sent in third-world countries over connections where bandwidth is a real issue. So we don't want to send 256 bytes of encrypted data. Most encryption algorithms are designed for natural language which has lots of patterns so the algorithm tries to obscure these patterns. We need something simpler but still standard.

E.g.

PIN: 1234

key: 'secret key of whatever length'

Example cipher text: 7301

XOR is a problem as anyone with two PIN codes and corresponding cipher text can guess the key.

What algorithm can we use? A Python implementation is what we are looking for.

### Edits:

Sorry for my lack of clarity;

- We're looking for symmetric encryption. Goal is to protect PINs from being easily discoverable by our own staff.
- Bandwidth is an issue. A realistic case: we might need to send data for say 500,000 cards over GPRS. If, say, the padded cipher text adds 256 bytes per card that would take an extra 5 hours to download. Hence we are looking for short cipher text.
- "Most encryption algorithms are designed for natural language" -> yes, this isn't true but, what I was trying to mean was that most popular encryption algorithms will assume the plaintext is not random, which doesn't match our case. Also, all the ones I looked at produced block output where each block is a particular number of bytes, so the length of a short plaintext isn't obvious. We don't need that, everyone knows most PINs are 4 digits.
- "Python implementation" -> just meant we want to be able to use it in python, i.e. an package exists for it.

Comment: For the sake of the people in the third world countries: **get an expert**.

Comment: `Most encryption algorithms are designed for natural language` Not really ... most enc. algos I know can handle arbitrary bit data. And to answer you should get more specific on the use case. I can´t even tell if you want something symmetric or not.

Comment: 256 bytes is not much larger than an HTTP header - are you sure you need to worry about using that many bytes? And how are they going to decrypt? The decryption software will be far larger than 256 bytes

Comment: Added clarifications, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

based on what you write, you have clearly not researched well on this topic ... i suggest to do so, **and** to get someone who knows what he/she is doing.

simply looking for a python implementation will not solve your problem.

crypto simply **can not** be securely implemented this way into any project.

however ... if you have some value (like a serial number, an account number) that might be used as a key derivation per PIN (and therefore is different for each pin), a stream cipher might be suitable for your scenario...

i write **might** because without additional info and a closer look at your project it is impossible to tell

so please see this as a solution that might be suitable, but isn't guaranteed to be suitable

so what you do is: take a funktion like PBKDF feed it your static secret key, and that per PIN value, to derive a unique key per pin

feed that key into a stream cipher like RC4, and drop a convenient number of bytes from the output of the cipher, like the first 256 byte for RC4 (simply throw them away, makes some possible attacks on the cipher a bit harder) ...

now take the next 14 bit of cipher output, and xor them on your PIN, treated as a number

the resulting number will be in the range from 0 to 16384

if the desired range has to be 0000 to 9999,

treat the 14 bit output as a number and simply add it to your PIN modulo 10000

to get your PIN back, calculate that 14 bit value again, subtract it from the cipher text, add 20000 modulo 10000 to make up for negative values, and you have the PIN

as a side note... you don't really need a stream cipher here, because you could already use the output of PBKDF, since your plain text is really small ... but PBKDF is meant to derive a key ... not as a cipher itself

Comment: RC4 is simple, but obsolescent.  Better to use AES in CTR mode (the equivalent of a stream cypher) or a more modern stream cypher, like Rabbit of Salsa-20.

Comment: Thanks DarkSquirrel42, this answer solves our problem. Sleeping on it I came up with pretty much exactly the same solution, so this confirms this idea. One problem I thought it would have is that if someone has a PIN and encrypted PIN for a card, they can work out that card's secret, and if we generate a new PIN, they could work it out, but that's OK, because normally we'd issue a new card if a card was compromised or lost.

Comment: another word of warning here ... all you have with this design is an encrypted value ... this alone, won't make an authentication scheme for something like access cards or credit cards, that can be securely checked against a remote service ... i can only recomend to hire someone who knows what he or she is doing for such things ...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer: the [Hasty Pudding cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasty_Pudding_cipher) can encrypt from and to any range of numbers you want.  You could set up a Hasty Pudding implementation to encrypt from [0000, 9999] to [0000, 9999].